# Packing unequal disks in a circle

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to solve a problem: where I have N circles, each with unique diameter and I want to fit them into the smallest possible circle.

I tried to search online for some solutions, but most of them are too complicated and I do not understand them.

I understand that there are several ways how to do that and that no approach is ideal.

Is there a general approach, which is not too difficult, but that still meets the requirement?

Thanks

Comment: In other words, you have a set of circles with radii $\{r_i\}_{i=1}^N$ and you seek the circle of minimum radius $r$ into which you can pack all the above-mentioned circles so they do not intersect?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Each circle can be with specific radii and I need pack all of them into circle with minimum radius. Inner circles do not intersect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you have a set of circles with radii ${r_i}^N_{i=1}$ and you seek the circle of minimum radius $r$ into which you can pack all the above-mentioned circles so they do not intersect.

Sounds like you want to look at the relevant [article by Collins and Stephenson](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772102000998?via%3Dihub). A short summary is available on [Wikipedia article on circle packing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem#Algorithmic_aspects) in the section **Algorithmic Aspects**.

Comment: I hoped, the solution will be easier as I am not mathematics :(.

Comment: @Izmail360 sorry about that. The Wiki article gives a simple algorithm you can try to follow